# What is a singleton object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, singleton

I'm starting to learn AngularJS, and in [one of the initial tutorials](http://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend) a `singleton` object is mentioned.

I have never heard of this, what is one? And why would you use one?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making a google query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that a class has only one instance and provide a global point of access to it. So a Singleton Pattern limits the number of instances of a particular object to just one and this single instance is called the singleton.